# Core Spotlight Index missing over time

Tags: ios, corespotlight

I'm trying to understand why my core spotlight indexes eventually don't show up anymore

My strategy is that I index the first time the user opens the app. After successful indexing, I never index again. Everything works great at first, the indexes appear in spotlight. Then over time (I'm unsure of how long, maybe weeks), the indexes stop appearing, even though I made absolutely no changes to them.

So therefore I'm trying to understand how the system handles indexes. Does it rebuild them, thus wiping any previous indexes out? So I would be responsible for re indexing?

Comment: Did you know about that property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corespotlight/cssearchableitem/1621680-expirationdate ?

Comment: Ah, no I did not. That must be it then! Thank you! Also it looks like its default value is 1 month, so that would make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `CSSearchableItem`, there is a property [`expirationDate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corespotlight/cssearchableitem/1621680-expirationdate)

> The date after which the searchable item should no longer exist.
>   Discussion
>   If you don’t set the expirationDate property appropriately, the system automatically expires the item after a period of time.

This should explain why your items disappear after some time.

Comment: I set the expirationDate to 'Date.distanceFuture' so it never expires.         item.expirationDate = Date.distantFuture